# Getting json keys from an array from an object using ArduinoJson

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32, arduinojson

I'm having trouble getting the keys (and values) from "prefs" in the following json.

```
{
  "cmd": "set",
  "prefs": [
    {
      "coins": 4
    },
    {
      "enable": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Code to process json:

```
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
    deserializeJson(doc,"{\"cmd\":\"set\",\"prefs\":[{\"coins\":4},{\"enable\":true}]}");
    JsonObject root=doc.as<JsonObject>();
    for (JsonPair kv : root) {
        Serial.println(kv.key().c_str());
        Serial.println(kv.value().as<char*>());
    }
    JsonObject prefs=doc["prefs"];
    for (JsonPair kv : prefs) {
        Serial.println("here\n");
        Serial.println(kv.key().c_str());
//        Serial.println(kv.value().as<const char*>());
    }
```

I would **expect** to see the following output:

```
cmd
set
prefs
coins
enable
```

But I only get what seems to be an empty `prefs` object:

```
cmd
set
prefs
```

The example shown in the [official docs](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonobject/begin_end/) almost gets me there, and is what I have in my code. This [example from github](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/issues/226) is similar, but I can't seem to adapt it to my case.

Comment: Maybe try making `prefs` a `JsonArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `prefs` is an array, convert it to `JsonArray`

```c++
JsonArray prefs = doc["prefs"].as<JsonArray>();
for (JsonObject a : prefs) {
    for (JsonPair kv : a) {
        Serial.println(kv.key().c_str());
        if (kv.value().is<int>()) {
            Serial.println(kv.value().as<int>());
        }
        else {
            Serial.println(kv.value().as<bool>());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. It was the inner for loop I hadn't thought to try. Nice touch with the is<int>() test as well.